# Logistic regression as classifier and overfitting

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification

I am using logistic regression to classify data into two classes.  The variable to predict (Y) is either 0 or 1.

I have found a rather good estimation of Y by logistic regression, and ended up using a set of the variables as predictor variables (the rest were quite correlated, or did not decrease the error a lot when added). My chosen set of variables is the optimum when using AIC as an optimization criteria.

Anyway, to the point: I have never used regression functions as classifiers before, and am not sure how to test this classifier in a good way. My professor suggested crossvalidation, but I don't understand why crossvalidation is a good choice is this case. I have a fairly large data set (196).

If my regression function is shown to be the best possible (given some defined optimum, I use AIC as criteria), why should I have to even test it?

Could my classifier be overfitted, and should I therefore leave out some data to only use as testing/validation in the end?

I am a bit new to this field.

Thanks in advance for all help.

(I have 196 feature vectors, and 22 features for this specific case, where I use 12 of them in my prediction of Y).

Comment: Logistic regression is intended for developing a probability (risk) model, not for classification.  And be sure to study proper scoring rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My chosen set of variables is the optimum when using AIC as an optimization criteria.

This is a data-driven optimization which always comes at a risk of overfitting (even if the model complexity is penalized).

Thus you need to *measure* the performance of your finally chosen model. Perfomance for unknown cases needs unknown test cases for the measurement, which can be achieved with a properly set-up cross validation.

I recommend to browse through the [cross validation questions here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-validation) to get an overview of what is possible, important, and recommended for cross validation.